# Make running thread execute method at command by main thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I want to have the main thread command a separate running thread to execute a method. The important part is that the separate thread is the one calling the method, it can not be executed on the main thread.

I have made a test-program doing what I want, but I highly doubt it's stable and would like to know if there is a better or rather right way to do this.

Below is the code:

**Class Main.java**

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SomeThread thread = new SomeThread();
        thread.start();

        try { Thread.sleep(100); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        // Manual wait ^, simulating that something should be done at a specific time
        thread.somethingShouldBeDone();

        thread.interrupt();

        // The thread is interrupted, nothing should be done
        thread.nothingShouldBeDone();
    }
}
```

**Class SomeThread.java**

```
public class SomeThread extends Thread
{
    private boolean doSomething = false;
    private boolean safeInterrupted = false;

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while (!safeInterrupted)
        {
            // System.out.println(new Date().getTime() + " - " + doSomething);
            if (doSomething)
            {
                doSomething();
                doSomething = false;
            }

            try { sleep(10); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    }

    private void doSomething()
    {
        System.out.println(new Date().getTime() + " - Thread did something - " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }

    void somethingShouldBeDone()
    {
        System.out.println(new Date().getTime() + " - Something should be done");
        doSomething = true;
    }

    void nothingShouldBeDone()
    {
        doSomething = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void interrupt()
    {
        System.out.println(new Date().getTime() + " - Interrupting");
        try { sleep(11); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        safeInterrupted = true;
        super.interrupt();
        System.out.println(new Date().getTime() + " - Interrupted");
    }
}
```

(I have experiened problems with isInterrupted(), which is why I use the variable safeInterrupted here..)

Thanks in advance for any answers or guidance.

Comment: Looks like this is more a java question other than Android. In Android, you can create a Looper object in any thread, and post messages to it from different threads.

Comment: The code will be used in an android application for networking with sockets. Android is unhappy when I do networking on main thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a android handler for this task.

```
Handler handler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());
handler.post<Your runnable>
```